# Seaborn plot two data sets on the same scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 data sets in Pandas Dataframe and I want to visualize them on the same scatter plot so I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.pairplot(x_vars=['Std'], y_vars=['ATR'], data=set1, hue='Asset Subclass')
sns.pairplot(x_vars=['Std'], y_vars=['ATR'], data=set2, hue='Asset Subclass')
plt.show()
```

But all the time I get 2 separate charts instead of a single one
[image]
How can I visualize both data sets on the same plot? Also can I have the same legend for both data sets but different colors for the second data set?

Comment: For the first question, can you concatenate the datasets?

Comment: @Charlie I can but then I have to make another column to distinct between data sets?

Comment: Can you post the sample of set1 and set2?

Comment: What version of seaborn are you using? '0.9.0' has a scatter plot function that may make this easier

Comment: seems like a reasonable question - and happens to be useful to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following should work in the latest version of `seaborn` (0.9.0)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

First we  concatenate the two datasets into one and assign a `dataset` column which will allow us to preserve the information as to which row is from which dataset.

```
concatenated = pd.concat([set1.assign(dataset='set1'), set2.assign(dataset='set2')])
```

Then we use the `sns.scatterplot` function from the latest seaborn version (0.9.0) and via the `style` keyword argument set it so that the markers are based on the `dataset` column:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='Std', y='ATR', data=concatenated,
                hue='Asset Subclass', style='dataset')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not always required. You can easily plot different dataframes on same axis with different colors and style. @MichaelDz

Comment: Glad it helped you out! @harvpan, not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean the `pd.concat` call is unnecessary and one could instead just write two calls to sns.scatterplot or `plt.scatter`?

Comment: Yes @tobsecret, that's what I meant. concatenating can be computationally sensitive and hog some large memory.

Comment: Fair point, though if your dataset is large enough to get you into computationally sensitive plotting territory, then you would likely have to opt for something like datashader anyways due to overplotting concerns. In the example plot given in the question, the amount of points appear to be in the hundreds, so concatenation should not be a limiting factor.

Comment: This thing does not work if we have different classes, unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean @YohanRoth?

Comment: @tobsecret calling `sns.scatterplot` or `plt.scatter` twice plots `set1` and `set2` on different plots, instead of being on 1plot. As noted, `pd.concat` can be computationally expensive with large `df`, unfortunately.

Comment: Again, see my previous comment on why that is irrelevant - seaborn is not meant to produce plots from a dataset that is too large to fit into memory, overplotting is not really tackled in the package.

Comment: How can you adapt the colour to each set?

Comment: @delViento, you can use the hue argument to change the color of the dots, as used with  `Asset Subclass` in this example. If you want to display an additional dimension, you can use style to change the markers used for the individual data points. See more here:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot