# Data analysis : compare two datasets for devising useful features for population segmentation

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science, data-analysis

Say I have two pandas dataframes, one containing data for general population and one containing the same data for a target group.

I assume this is a very common use case of population segmentation. My first idea to explore the data would be to perform some vizualization using e.g. seaborn Facetgrid or barplot & scatterplot or something like that to  get a general idea of the trends and differences. 
However, I found out that this operation is not as straightforward as I thought as seaborn is made to analyze one dataset and not compare two datasets.

I found this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732867/seaborn-plot-two-data-sets-on-the-same-scatter-plot/51733133) which provides a solution. But I am wondering how would people go about if if the dataframe was huge and a concat operation would not be possible ?

Datashader does not seem to provide such features as far as I have seen ?

Thanks for any ideas on how to go about such task

Answer (score 1):

I would use the library `Dask` when data is too big for pandas. Dask is made by the same people who created pandas and it is a little bit more advanced, because it is a big data tool, but it has some of the same features including `concat`. I found dask easy enough to use and am using it for a couple of projects where I have dozens of columns and tens of millions of rows.