# Plot two one seaborn plot from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I try to plot two dataframes with seaborn into one figure.

given these test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Name'] = 'Adam'
df.iloc[::5, 4] = 'Berta'

df.head(10)
    A   B   C   D   Name
0   40  75  45  6   Berta
1   52  98  55  44  Adam
2   57  61  70  17  Adam
3   52  5   20  28  Adam
4   63  53  74  49  Adam
5   53  28  97  26  Berta
6   64  38  73  56  Adam
7   25  65  34  64  Adam
8   95  91  92  60  Adam
9   6   54  5   58  Adam
```

and

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df1['Location'] = 'New York'
df1.iloc[::5, 4] = 'Tokyo'
df1.head(10)

   A    B   C   D   Location
0   89  16  23  15  Tokyo
1   7   35  26  21  New York
2   64  94  51  61  New York
3   84  16  15  36  New York
4   55  62  0   2   New York
5   73  93  4   1   Tokyo
6   93  11  27  69  New York
7   14  52  50  45  New York
8   26  77  86  32  New York
9   21  10  68  11  New York
```

A)The first plot I would like to plot a relplot or scatterplot where both dataframes have the same x and y axes, but a different "hue". If I try:

```
sb.relplot(data=df, x='Name', y='C', hue="Name", height=8.27, aspect=11.7/8.27)
sb.relplot(data=df1, x='Location', y='C', hue="Location", height=8.27, aspect=11.7/8.27)
plt.show()
```

The latter plot will overwrite the first or creates a new one. Any ideas?

B) Now we have the same y-axes (let's say "amount"), but with different x-axes (strings).
I found this here: [How to overlay two seaborn relplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750489/how-to-overlay-two-seaborn-relplots) and it looks pretty good, but if I try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sb.scatterplot(x="Name", y='A', data=df, hue="Name", ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sb.scatterplot(data=df1, x='Location', y='A', hue="Location", ax =ax2)
plt.show()
```

then the second scatterplot plots the values over the values of the first one overwriting the names for x. But I would like to add the second scatterplot on the right. Is this possible?

In my opinion it doesn't make sense to concatenate the two dataframes.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn plot two data sets on the same scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732867/seaborn-plot-two-data-sets-on-the-same-scatter-plot)

Comment: @PeCaDe not really, because I have different sets of hue and x axis.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Note that to be answerable on StackOverflow your question needs reproducible test data. Also, note that `sns.relplot` is a figure-level function; so every time it is called it creates a new figure. For your second question, please explain what you mean by "to the right". Maybe you just want 2 subplots?

Comment: Ah I see, I apologize. I'm on my Phone right now, please just use some np random values.

Comment: Okay, I'll deliver some tomorrow.

Comment: @JohanC I added some test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gathered all questions you asked I assume you either want to plot two subplots in one row for two DataFrames or plot two sets of data on one figure.

As for the 'A' plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharey=True)
sb.scatterplot(data=df, x='Name', y='A', hue='Name', 
               ax=ax[0])
sb.scatterplot(data=df1, x='Location', y='A', hue='Location',
               ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Here I created both `fig` and `ax` using `plt.subplots()` so then I could locate each scatter plot on a separate subplot, indicating number of rows (1) and columns (2) and a shared Y-axis. Here's what I got (sorry for not bothering for legend location and other decorations):

[image]

As for the 'B' plot, if you would want everything on one plot, then you may try:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4))
sb.scatterplot(data=df, x='Name', y='A', hue='Name', palette=['blue', 'orange'], 
               ax=ax)
sb.scatterplot(data=df1, x='Location', y='A', hue='Location', palette=['red', 'green'], 
               ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Name/Location')
plt.show()
```

Here I made a single subplot and assigned both scatter plots to it. Might require color mapping and renaming X-axis:

[image]

Comment: Thx! the last one is what I want :-) One question: Is it possivble to remove/change the title of the legend?

Comment: @MisterY sure, just add `ax.legend(title=None)` before `plt.show()` to remove or any other string you want for `title` to change it.